# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'id not supplied'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Full error is this:Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'id not supplied' in /var/www/html/pdo/Delete.php on line 12 + ( ! ) Exception: id not supplied in /var/www/html/pdo/Delete.php on line 12.I am testing a page to call a delete function that deletes the row that matches the id I give in my test.  It works,  it deletes the row with that id.  But gives me that warning.  Here is my code:

```
<?php

    include_once("StudentManager.php");
    //assumption is that the following parameters are passed to this file   
    //$id to be deleted.

    //Tester
    StudentManager::Delete(6); // 6 was the id I deleted.

    extract($_REQUEST); 

    if(!isset($id)){
        throw new Exception("id not supplied");
        echo "Bad";  //It does not get to this.
    } //else {

        //echo StudentManager::Delete($id);

    //}



?>
//Delete(id) and returns the number of rows affected by the delete
    public static function Delete($id){
    $db = StudentManager::getPDOConnection();
    $sql = "DELETE FROM people WHERE id=".$id;

    $di = $db->prepare($sql);     

    $di->execute(array(":id"=>$id));       

    $affected_rows = $di->rowCount();                                    

    echo "<p>$affected_rows rows were Deleted.</p>";
    $db = null;
    return $affected_rows;

} //end of delete
```

Comment: Please don't dump code to the comments. edit our original post to add the code.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard,  thanks, I deleted my comment and added it to the code.

Comment: Do you know what prepared statements are? If yes, why aren't you binding the id using prepared statements?

Comment: @N.B.,  yes you were right, I fixed that up better, but it still gives me the exception.  It still works, as in deleting it from the database, but it throws a fatal at me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
throw new Exception("id not supplied");
```

This line throws the exception that causes the fatal error you're seeing.

It's run under this condition:

```
if(!isset($id)){
```

So obviously, the condition matches, which means that the `$id` variable is not set.

Also, `extract($_REQUEST)` is extremely bad practice.

Simple scope example:

```
function foo($a) {
    $a = 5;
    echo $a; //5
}
$a = 42;
echo $a; //42
foo($a); //will echo 5
echo $a; //Still 42. Different $a.
```

Comment: But I thought that my check is to see if the id is not passed in, and it is in my test. So the !isset should ignore it, since it is set.  or am I looking at it wrong.

Comment: Why would it check anything like that? The `$id` passed to the isset and the `$id` passed to the function are different. Read about how scope works in PHP (it's not that complicated really).

Comment: Yes it was the scope.  I was testing my code in the wrong place.  It works great now, that I am testing it from elsewhere.